# Can I ask questions related to CMMI process?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

My organisation is starting to follow the CMMI (Capability Maturity Model Integration) process.
We are all quite new to it.

I know that Stackoverflow.com is for asking questions related to Programming but may we ask questions related to CMMI process in Stackoverflow.com or may be some other Stack Exchange websites?

Comment: see: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/165773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Programmers.SE (and especially it's [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)):

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about...
>
> - [...]
> - development methodologies
> - [...]
> - quality assurance
> - [...]
>
> ...then you're in the right place to ask your question!

But be careful; CMMI is a *general* QA process, not specific to programming. Asking questions on how to apply it to a software development process might well still be on topic though.

The rule of thumb for choosing between Programmers and SO is: Are you at the whiteboard? Use Programmers. Design done but stuck coding? Go to Stack Overflow.